# Django React Axios

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a post request to a Django server using React with Axios. However, I am getting a redirect 302 on the server side.

Just followed all suggestions in this post here [CSRF with Django, React+Redux using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254562/csrf-with-django-reactredux-using-axios)
unsuccessfully :(

However, what I have done so far is the following:
Sat the default axios CookieName and HeaderName (on the javascript side):

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "XCSRF-Token";
```

Got this in `settings.py` as well:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XCSRF-Token"
```

And here is how the post request looks like:

```
axios(
    {
        method: 'post',
        url: `/api/${selectedEntryType}_entry`,
        data: {
            "test": "test"
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': document.cookie.split('=')[1],
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
)
```

Another thing that I have tried is to make the post request from the Django rest api UI:
[image: Django rest api UI]

and it does work successfully.

The only differences in the Request Headers when I make the request from the UI and from JS are:
`Accept`, `Content-Length`, and `Referer`, which I don't see how could they be problematic.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to fix it by changing the url (`url:'/en/api/endpoint/'`) I was posting to, because apparently for a POST request:

> You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/en/api/endpoint/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings

After that I started getting `Forbidden 403`, but by adding:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_protect)
def post(self, request):
    return Response()
```

and also changed the defaults in JS to:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
```

and removed `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XCSRF-Token"` from `settings.py`.

It worked.

Hope this helps somebody in the future.