# ReactJS & Django : How can I send csrf token with axios in a proper way?

Tags: django, reactjs, cookies, csrf, axios

I'm pretty new to using ReactJS with Django.

What I want is simple. I want to send a request to make an account.
Front-End server and the Back-End server are completely divided. They only communicates with AJAX, and nothing more, they're not even in the same server.

I tried several ways to send a request to make an account, and nothing worked.

Here's what I tried in JavaScript:

1. Add an option called `withCredentials:true` on axios. This adds cookie on header, but django says "csrftoken incorrect or not set."
2. Set the following:

   ```
   axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
   axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
   ```

-> this doesn't make any effects.

3. Set the following:

   ```
   axios.defaults.headers.common = {
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : (document.cookie).replace("csrftoken=", "")
   };
   ```

-> this makes axios to make only "option" method requests. but I don't know why and of course, this doesn't work.

Here's what I changed in Django's settings.py:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "X-CSRFToken"
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
)
```

and of course, I added @ensure_csrf_cookie just above the view that does some register things.

Is there any way to fix this? I spend a lot of my time for this. I REALLY need your help. thanks.

Comment: Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/django-react-csrftoken?

Comment: to Arpit, Yeah, that's the one also I've tried. I setted it for my view that does some register things

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF with Django, React+Redux using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254562/csrf-with-django-reactredux-using-axios)

Comment: To Kiara, yeah I've also tried it.

Answer (score 2):

You can install `js-cookie` via npm (or other methods that suites you) link [here](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/)

Call the Cookies in `js-cookie` like so:
`import Cookies from 'js-cookie';`

Then take the cookies by doing: `Cookies.get()`

`Cookies.get()` gives you an object which contains the `csrftoken`. So you can do something like this overall:

`const cookies = Cookies.get()`

Then in your headers in your axios request you can add this:

`headers: new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json", 'X-CSRFToken': cookies.csrftoken})`