# axios post to django failing due to csrf

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I am using React + Django and trying to make a post request using axios but it is failing due to csrf. I have tried all the answers posted on internet to similar problem but none of them are working for some weird reason.

```
//Django View
def createUser(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    resp = {
      'username' : username,
      'email' : email
    }
    return JsonResponse(resp)



//Axios Post
 axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/createUser/',{
       username : 'xyz',
       email : 'xyz@gmail.com'
    },
    {
       headers: {
         Content-Type': 'application/json',
       }
    });
```

tried adding defaults

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
```

but still getting csrf failed. I know i can do @csrf_exempt on the view but i want to keep the csrf check.

Comment: Are you sure its `X-CSRFTOKEN` and not `X-CSRF-TOKEN`

Comment: @Advaith i followed this SO answer and it says X-CSRFTOKEN
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254562/csrf-with-django-reactredux-using-axios?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Along with the X-CSRFToken header, also include the cookies in the axios request using `withCredentials: true`

[My original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842141/csrf-verification-fails-in-production-for-cross-domain-post-request/57511705#57511705)