# CSRF Verification fails in production for Cross Domain POST request

Tags: django, cross-domain, csrf

The HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN header does not match what is inside the csrftoken cookie.

How can I examine the cookie? Set-Cookie is not displayed in the Response header for Cross Domain requests.

I have already followed instructions found in:

[CSRF with Django, React+Redux using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254562/csrf-with-django-reactredux-using-axios)

Interestingly I found "X-CSRFTOKEN" translates to "HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN" on the server request header.

Works fine in the development env under localhost (although I am using 2 different ports - one for django and the other my frontend).

UPDATE:

It seems the csrktoken cookie is not correctly set for cross domain rquests (although the browser displays it in the Request Header) so the X-CSRFTOKEN does not get sent.

I ended up adding an API call to return the current csrftoken using a GET request and then sending it back using the X-CSRFTOKEN header.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned how you're getting the `csrftoken` from the server in the first place, so I'm assuming it's already present in your browser.
Along with the `X-CSRFToken` header, also include the cookies in the request using `withCredentials: true`.
I'm using the `js-cookie` library to get the `csrftoken` from the cookies.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

axios({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
    method: 'post',
    withCredentials: true,
    data: {
        query: `
            {
                // Your query here
            }     
        `
    },
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken')
    }
})
```

Also add `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` to your `settings.py`, assuming you are using `django-cors-headers`. Otherwise, the cookies won't be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the `X-CSRFTOKEN` header accessible via the CORS [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) directive. Example:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-CSRFTOKEN
```

This header has to be set by your API or web server, so that the browser will see it during the CORS preflight request.

Comment: django-cors-headers does this. Actually the header is being sent. It is the cookie that is not. Despite being displayed in the Request headers in chrome devtools.