# Post Request shows 403 not found error even tough permission class in django rest framework view sets is set to allow any

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, axios, django-rest-viewsets

I am trying to store the data in the form using post method. To do that i have set the permissions as `AllowAny`. I have checked the POST method using Postman and it works but when I use axios to post the same data it returns 403 error.

I have already tried using fixes provided in the given link description but that add more exceptions. 
[CSRF with Django, React+Redux using Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254562/csrf-with-django-reactredux-using-axios/42098817#42098817)

The error description as given in console

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

Python django rest framework code

```
#viewset class from python
class feedbackViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = feedback.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = feedbackSerializer
```

Java script code using axios to POST the data to the server

```
//axios post method
export const addFeedback = feedback => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/feedbacks/", feedback)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_FEEDBACK,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Form code contains the on submit methods that are to be called.

```
//form component code
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { addFeedback } from "../../actions/feedbacks";

export class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    description: ""
  };

  static propTypes = {
    addFeedback: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, description } = this.state;
    const feedback = { name, email, description };
    this.props.addFeedback(feedback);
  };
  render() {
    const { name, email, description } = this.state;
    return (
      //some form generation code
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { addFeedback }
)(Form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out that link [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

I assume that you are trying to send a MIME type of x-www-form-urlencoded, which needs to manually stringify your data.

```
const qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
```