# Error 403 CSRF cookie not set. axios post request to django server

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I have been trying to send a simple post request to my django server using axios package in react. But everytime, I'm getting a backend error saying CSRF Cookie not set.
Here is my React Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let csrfToken = getCsrfToken()
    console.log(csrfToken)
    axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/getStats',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "x-csrftoken": csrfToken
        },
        data: { "city": "pune" }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

This is added in my django server:
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "x-csrftoken"

Edit: I haven't yet used any form. I was just trying to send static data as Pune using axios when my component mounted.

Comment: Try allowing credentials - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734106/113962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Data Write

```
data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
            "city": "pune"
        },
```

also add {% csrf_token %}

```
<form>
  anywhere out this {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the csrftoken to the data, I had the same problem with ajax, and Jquery

```
  [...]
  method: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/getStats',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: { "city": "pune" ,
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrfToken}
  [...]
```

Comment: @AtharvaChavan  did you try with the keyword "x-csrftoken"

Comment: do you have the value stored in csrfToken?

Comment: const getCsrfToken = () => {
    const csrf = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*csrftoken\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return csrf ? csrf.pop() : '';
};

is what I'm using to get the csrfToken value.

Comment: @AtharvaChavan does it return a value?

Comment: do you have {% csrf_token %} in your template?

Comment: Yes. I can see it in the console.  
"ybUHWOAK4uFJGBTLnGyySqxAh8DxwMq3FIbFsfKsXldPiXcYxVfdxdbUbsLfidCM"

Comment: No I'm not using a form template. Just sending a request through axios.