# CSRF validation works from Postman but not React/Axios

Tags: python, reactjs, django, axios

It's honestly a catastrophic blow to the ego I haven't already figured this out--spent 6 hours so far...

I have a React app running off a Django Rest Framework backend. For the password reset functionality I am using Django's builtin view (`auth_views.PasswordResetView`). I have a form in React that accepts an email and sends a post request to reset the users password. The way I send the data in postman is:

```
Url: http://192.168.0.85:8000/reset_password
Body: {'email': 'blabla@bla.com'}
Headers: {'X-CSRFToken': OGH9iUEtGPqntMYifQ5kiin2ufV9tK39tbp9Wmh6tLST0DXCXSkY8mOvyq5AjjnZ}
```

...and it works like a charm! Until I try to replicate the same exact call using axios in React:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.post('http://192.168.0.85:8000/reset_password',{'email': 'blabla@bla.com'},{headers}))
```

...this results in a 403 error with this message from the backend:
`WARNING:django.security.csrf:Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /reset_password`

I've spent 6 hours googling and experimenting and can't figure out for the life of me why the Axios request would be any different than the Postman one. This problem is particularly infuriating because @csrf_exempt won't work on the django builtin views.

Here are the headers from a successful request in Postman:

```
X-CSRFToken: OGH9iUEtGPqntMYifQ5kiin2ufV9tK39tbp9Wmh6tLST0DXCXSkY8mOvyq5AjjnZ
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 91cbbfe7-b434-45fc-97ec-7d442c091070
Host: 192.168.0.85:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 33
Cookie: csrftoken=gawXPEZQfN4qC4aKPhiIvK5qpjvkp4WCVFeXt6Ct2JwW9V94xjxmlOwTtuFLfDgs
```

...and from the failed request using Axios from React:

```
baseURL: "http://192.168.0.85:8000"
data: "{\"email\":\"blabla@bla.com\"}"
headers:
Accept: "*/*"
Authorization: ""
Content-Type: "application/json"
X-CSRFToken: "udd4yAGCJuTxw95kCdHYwwEQmGwu1bwxqEQjZhI56v1qWY143S4IPCrUSvk9xkV8"
__proto__: Object
maxBodyLength: -1
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "/reset_password"
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName: "csrftoken"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken"
__proto__: Object
isAxiosError: true
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550363/7838574 ?

With emphasis on the `settings.py` portion. That is what tripped me up about a week ago.

Honestly great job keeping at this and asking for help! Programming can be insanely frustrating and once the hurdle is behind you very rewarding!