# Error when reactjs requests from Django server (403 error / CORS)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a reactjs project that makes requests using API to django-rest-framework.
It was working fine before, but I'm not sure what made it stop working.

I'm already using django-cors-headers.

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

My reactjs request:

```
fetch('/api/user/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(obj)
})
```

The error I got in the django terminal:

```
Forbidden: /api/user/
[06/Oct/2021 01:15:31] "POST /api/user/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

Error in console and network tabs in reactjs browser:

```
// console error:
UserPage.js:65 POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/ 403 (Forbidden)

//network error:
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

//Preview in Networks tab:
detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

**UPDATE**
my reactjs terminal:

```
Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://172.22.192.1:3000
```

When I open my react project using `http://172.22.192.1:3000` it works fine, but using `http://localhost:3000` it still can't send a POST request.

Comment: I'm not sure why some downvoted, if I'm missing something let me knwo so I can add it.

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve your issue, you can use `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` instead of `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` in the Django settings file.**

*REPLACE :*

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

*BY :*

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',  # React default port = 3000
    'http://localhost:8000',  # Django default port = 8000
)
# Change the url to suit your needs.
```

**NB :** The `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` define to `True` must allow all origins, but i faced the same issue before and replace it by `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` solved it. Then try it.

**Update for Django CSRF-TOKEN :**
[This link may solve your issue about csrf_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254562/csrf-with-django-reactredux-using-axios)

Comment: Tried it but no luck.

Comment: I added a new error that I found in the networks tab, does this mean that I should add a token?

Comment: Are you using [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#sessionauthentication) ? On your api ?

Comment: I don't think so, I do have a superuser but when requesting I don't require any login or authentication.

Comment: When I opened the browser using this: http://172.22.192.1:3000, It worked. But still doesn't work using: http://localhost:3000

Comment: In your api `views.py` file add `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`. After that, wrap the views in the `urls.py` file by the decorator like this : `url("api/users/', csrf_exempt(UserApiView.as_view())),`

Comment: Have you added `'http://localhost:3000'` in `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` also ?

Comment: Tried ```path('user/', csrf_exempt(views.getUserBills))``` in urls.py
```@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def getUserBills(request):``` in views.py
Still got the same error.
and yes I added ```'http://localhost:3000'```